# Variable in create table identity

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table with in a SP.

```
CREATE TABLE #bclist (
            bcastid INT
            ,userid INT
            ,etype INT
            ,articles0 BIGINT
            ,seq INT identity(1, 1)
            )
```

I also have a variable @nextseq
What I want is somthingh like below

```
CREATE TABLE #bclist (
            bcastid INT
            ,userid INT
            ,etype INT
            ,articles0 BIGINT
            ,seq INT identity(@nextseq, 1)
            )
```

But SQl server doesn’t permit this .Any solution ?

Comment: perhaps you should post the 'actual' problem you are trying to solve; smells like a row_number() solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#bclist, RESEED, @nextseq)
```

But it will not work if your SP is not running from dbowner.
Another thingh you can do is to reseed the table.

```
if @nextseq > 1 
        begin
                 TRUNCATE table #bclist
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT #bclist ON  
            INSERT INTO #bclist (seq) 
            VALUES (@nextseq-1 )  
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT #bclist OFF  
            DELETE FROM #bclist 
         End
```

Don’t forget the if condition otherwise in you seq coulmn you will get values from 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about a global temp table?

```
DECLARE @foo  varchar(5);
SET @foo = '4';

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);

-- a global temp table will exist for the lifetime of
-- the connection
SET @query = replace(N'
CREATE TABLE ##bclist (
            bcastid INT
            ,userid INT
            ,etype INT
            ,articles0 BIGINT
            ,seq INT identity(@seed, 1)
            )', '@seed', @foo)

EXECUTE(@query)

INSERT INTO
    ##bclist
SELECT 0,1,2,3
select * from ##bclist

drop table ##bclist
```

Results

```
bcastid   userid   etype   articles0   seq
0         1        2       3           4
```